# How to bundle source files into one file?

Tags: rust

I created a Rust binary project with `cargo new --bin`, and ended up with multiple source files.

However, Coursera only accepts single source file solutions.

How can I bundle all project files into one `main.rs` file?

Comment: Any hint what purpose this should fulfill? I don't see how this would make any sense.

Comment: I want to submit my program to a Coursera course, but the course accepts only one source file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a tool like [rust-sourcebundler](https://github.com/lpenz/rust-sourcebundler).

Answer (score 2):

In Rust, every file is a module. But that *doesn't* mean that every module needs its own file.

> I created a Rust binary project with `cargo new --bin`, and ended up with multiple source files.

`cargo new --bin` creates only one source file, `src/main.rs`. If you created some other `.rs` file, you must have put a `mod` declaration so you could use it inside `main.rs`:

```
// main.rs
mod foobar;
use foobar::Foo;
```

```
// foobar.rs
struct Foo {}
```

But instead of creating a separate file, you can put the contents directly in `main.rs` by changing the `mod` line:

```
// main.rs
mod foobar {
    struct Foo {}
}
use foobar::Foo; // works exactly the same
```

Comment: I know I can bundle the files in the way that you mentioned. I want a tool that automatically does it, because I want the files remain separated for maintainability.